# Create new file, based on 500 articles

Tags: text, files-and-directories

I've got a folder with 500 newspaper articles. Each article is saved in a seperate file with a number in the title like "1.txt", "2.txt". Each article has a date but it is not clear in which line the date is printed. I would like to seperate the date from the article and put them in two columns. The purpose is that I can make selection of articles based on periods of time.

A article looks like this:

The Light of Truth
ENORMOUS IPO MAKES THE BILLIONAIRE
2013/12/18
CENTRUM, Tethys - the president and PRESIDENT international Sten can add another description to its name:.......

```
fname = FileNameJoin[{"E:\\data\\MC1 Data\\MC1 Data\\articles\\", 
"testfile3.txt"}];

s = OpenWrite[fname]
For[i = 1, i < 20, i++,
test1 = Import["E:\\data\\MC1 Data\\MC1 Data\\articles\\" <> ToString[i] <>".txt","Text"];

test2 = {
  StringCases[test1, DatePattern[{"Year", "Month", "Day"}]],StringCases[ToLowerCase[test1], RegularExpression["\\w(?<!\\d)[\\w'-]*"]]};

WriteString[s, test2, "\n"];
```

]

When I open the file,

```
test1 = Import["E:\\data\\MC1 Data\\MC1 Data\\articles\\testfile3.txt"]
```

I will see this:

```
{{2013/12/18}, {the, light, of, truth, enormous, ipo, makes, the, 
billionaire, of, sanjorge, centrum,}}
{2009/06/21}, {news, online, today, protest, turns, violent, in, 
abila, abila, kronos, a, rally, of, hundreds, of, protestors, allied, 
with, the, protectors, of, kronos, movement, turned, to, violence}
```

The structure of this file is like this :{{..},{..}} and I can't make a selection like

```
Select[file[All,{1,2}]], #[[1]]<"2009/06/21"&]
```

Anyone a suggestion how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are using methods to write and read the data which don't preserve the expression structure.

`WriteString` puts the `OutputForm` of an expression into the file, and so does not preserve the quote marks around strings. Here is a simple example:

```
data = {{"one", "two"}, {"three", "four"}};

Do[WriteString["test.txt", data[[i]], "\n"], {i, 2}];
Close["test.txt"];
```

Here' s the file it creates :

[image]

Looking at the file contents above, you can see that there is going to be an interpretation problem however you import the data. Is it a list of lists containing symbols `one`, `two` etc? Or is it a list of strings, where the strings just happen to contain curly brackets? Or maybe the whole file is one big string with carriage returns in it?

`Import` goes for the latter interpretation, because you are using the .txt format which is expected to contain text.

```
Import["test.txt"] // InputForm

(* "{one, two}\n{three, four}" *)
```

This is what happens with your data - it is imported as a single string.

What you can do is to use `Write` and `ReadList` instead of `WriteString` and `Import`. `Write` writes expressions in `InputForm`, so you get this:

```
Do[Write["test.txt", data[[i]]], {i, 2}];
Close["test.txt"];
```

[image]

Notice that the strings now have quote marks around them. This file can be imported using `ReadList`, with each line being correctly interpreted as a *Mathematica* expression:

```
ReadList["test.txt"] // InputForm

(* {{"one", "two"}, {"three", "four"}} *)
```

### Comparing dates

For the final part of your code, you can use DateDifference to compare date strings. For example

```
isbefore[date1_String, date2_String] := DateDifference[date1, date2] >= 0

Select[{"2013/12/18", "2010/12/18", "2001/12/18"}, # ~isbefore~ "2009/06/21" &]

(* {"2001/12/18"} *)
```

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks for your comment. The question is about the fileformat after WriteString[s, test2, "\n"]; The result is a file with {{..},{..}} as structure.

Comment: @MichielvanMens, sorry, I missed the point of the question. See my edit.

Comment: Great! You give a good explanation. Thanks for that.